# getMappedResults() doesn't map correctly the raw result

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I am having problem getting mapped Result when using unwind operations in aggregation.

Following are my dependencies. Below the dependency I have mentioned the two model classes which I use with the aggregation code at the last. I am getting data in result in native query as well as Spring query. But the difference is that the Spring query result even though has documents, the orgMap array is empty. Whereas the document returned by the native query has one data for each document in the orgMap array.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- mongodb java driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring data mongodb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>





        package com.mongodb.model.user;

        import java.util.HashSet;
        import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
        import org.springframework.data.annotation.PersistenceConstructor;
        import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
        import com.alta.mongodb.model.user.UserOrgMap;

        @Document(collection = "users")

        public class Users {

            public Users() {
                super();
            }

            @PersistenceConstructor
            public Users(String userId, String login, String firstName, String lastName, 
                    HashSet<UserOrg> userOrg) {
                super();
                this.userId = userId;
                this.login = login;
                this.firstName = firstName;
                this.lastName = lastName;
                this.userOrgMap = userOrgMap;
            }

            @Id
            private String userId;
            private String login;
            private String firstName;
            private String lastName;
            private HashSet<UserOrgMap> userOrgMap;


            public String getUserId() {
                return userId;
            }
            public void setUserId(String userId) {
                this.userId = userId;
            }
            public String getLogin() {
                return login;
            }
            public void setLogin(String login) {
                this.login = login;
            }
            public String getFirstName() {
                return firstName;
            }
            public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
                this.firstName = firstName;
            }
            public String getLastName() {
                return lastName;
            }
            public void setLastName(String lastName) {
                this.lastName = lastName;
            }

            public HashSet<UserOrgMap> getUserOrgMap() {
                return userOrgMap;
            }
            public void setUserOrgMap(HashSet<UserOrgMap> userOrgMap) {
                this.userOrgMap = userOrgMap;
            }

            @Override
            public int hashCode() {
                final int prime = 31;
                int result = 1;
                result = prime * result + ((firstName == null) ? 0 : firstName.hashCode());
                result = prime * result + ((lastName == null) ? 0 : lastName.hashCode());
                result = prime * result + ((login == null) ? 0 : login.hashCode());
                result = prime * result + ((userId == null) ? 0 : userId.hashCode());
                result = prime * result + ((userOrgMap == null) ? 0 : userOrgMap.hashCode());
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean equals(Object obj) {
                if (this == obj)
                    return true;
                if (obj == null)
                    return false;
                if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                    return false;
                Users other = (Users) obj;
                if (firstName == null) {
                    if (other.firstName != null)
                        return false;
                } else if (!firstName.equals(other.firstName))
                    return false;
                if (lastName == null) {
                    if (other.lastName != null)
                        return false;
                } else if (!lastName.equals(other.lastName))
                    return false;
                if (login == null) {
                    if (other.login != null)
                        return false;
                } else if (!login.equals(other.login))
                    return false;
                if (userId == null) {
                    if (other.userId != null)
                        return false;
                } else if (!userId.equals(other.userId))
                    return false;
                if (userOrgMap == null) {
                    if (other.userOrgMap != null)
                        return false;
                } else if (!userOrgMap.equals(other.userOrgMap))
                    return false;
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "Users [userId=" + userId + ", login=" + login + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName
                        + ", userOrgMap=" + userOrgMap + "]";
            }


        }

    package com.mongodb.model.user;

    import org.springframework.data.annotation.PersistenceConstructor;

    public class UserOrg {



        private String orgId;
        private String createdbyuser;

        public UserOrg() {
            super();
        }

        public UserOrg(String orgId, String createdbyuser) {
            super();
            this.orgId = orgId;
            this.createdbyuser = createdbyuser;
        }

        public String getOrgId() {
            return orgId;
        }

        public void setOrgId(String orgId) {
            this.orgId = orgId;
        }

        public String getCreatedbyuser() {
            return createdbyuser;
        }

        public void setCreatedbyuser(String createdbyuser) {
            this.createdbyuser = createdbyuser;
        }



        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((createdbyuser == null) ? 0 : createdbyuser.hashCode());
            result = prime * result + ((orgId == null) ? 0 : orgId.hashCode());
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            UserOrg other = (UserOrg) obj;
            if (createdbyuser == null) {
                if (other.createdbyuser != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!createdbyuser.equals(other.createdbyuser))
                return false;
            if (orgId == null) {
                if (other.orgId != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!orgId.equals(other.orgId))
                return false;

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "UserOrg [orgId=" + orgId + ", createdbyuser=" + createdbyuser + "]";
        }




    }

 Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
                 unwind("userOrgMap")
            );


        AggregationResults<User> groupResults = mongoOperation.aggregate(aggregation,"users", User.class);

        System.out.println(" groupResults raw result "+groupResults.getRawResults().get("result"));

        List<User> result = groupResults.getMappedResults();

System.out.println(" result "+result);


Output : 
groupResults raw result 

[ { "_id" : "user_1" , "login" : "123" , "firstName" : "abc" , "lastName" : "xyz" ,  "userOrgMap" : { "orgId" : "org_1" , "createdbyuser" : "user_2" } , 
  { "_id" : "user_2" ,  "login" : "789" , "firstName" : "qqq" , "lastName" : "aaa" , "userOrgMap" : { "orgId" : "org_1" , "createdbyuser" : "user_3" } 
 ]



 result 

 [
  User [userId=user_1, login=123, firstName=abc, lastName=xyz, userOrgMap=[] ], 
  User [userId=user_2, login=789, firstName=qqq, lastName=aaa, userOrgMap=[],]
 ]


I want to know why userOrgMap array is empty instead of having value similar to the output shown for raw results.
```

Comment: You are expecting `userOrgMap` document  to map to collection type which is not possible and thus spring returns as empty array. You can create a `userDTO` with `userOrgMap` as `UserOrg` instead of `Set<UserOrg >` and other fields. This should map correctly. Btw, I'm not sure why are mapping it back to `users`class. I can help you more if you can share what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The actual user model has lot of attributes. What I had posted is a minified   version of it. In my actual implementation it is userOrgMap. But still the arry is empty.

Comment: My requirement is to unwind an array inside a document and get multiple document mapped to the document model.

Comment: The problem I am facing here is that the raw result is giving multiple documents with each document having the userOrgMap array with the single value. Whereas , when I use getMappedResult to map the raw result to my model, the userOrgMap array is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`userOrgMap` not an array in raw result but just a single document.

You have to two options.

Add an extra field `userOrgMap` `userOrgMapSingle` in `User` model and add  the `unwind` alias  as `userOrgMapSingle` in aggregation query.

Or

Add `project` stage to convert single document into array with a single document for  mapping it to an existing `userOrgMap` collection  type.

Something like

```
{$project:{userOrgMap:["$userOrgMap"]}}
```

Spring Mongo Data Equivalent

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
            unwind("userOrgMap"),
            new AggregationOperation() {
               @Override
              public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {
              return new BasicDBObject("$addFields", new BasicDBObject("userOrgMap", Arrays.asList("$userOrgMap")));
          }
      }
 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I prefer the second approach because I don't have to do any changes to the User Model. May I know the SpringData equivalent for the above mentioned native query ?

Comment: Hello, would you know the answer to this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44041506/how-to-check-that-a-user-has-already-voted-on-a-post

Comment: @karmaker You are welcome. I can't find any standard api methods to help with this, so I've used `AggregationOperation` with `BasicDBObject` for adding `$addFields` aggregation stage. I'll update the answer if I find api method.

Comment: Thanks. But I am having a problem. The problem is that I am using Mongo version 3.2.10 which doesn't support $addFields. $addFields was newly introduced in version 3.4. Is there any alternative ?

Comment: You are welcome. Change aggregation operation to  `$project`, but now you will need to add all the fields you would like to keep along with the updated `userOrgMap` field.

Comment: Thanks. Let's say my fields are "a" ,"b" and userOrgMap. In this case , how does the API looks.

Comment: Np. Something like `return new BasicDBObject("$project", new BasicDBObject("userOrgMap", Arrays.asList("$userOrgMap")).append("a", 1).append("b", 1));`

Comment: I tried. But the result of getMappedResult is giving we HashSet of HashMap instead of HashSet of my model which resulted in error. I think I will go for the first approach. Need help on the equivalent Spring data query for the first option.

Comment: Try `Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(unwind("userOrgMap"),project(a,b).and("$userOrgMap").as("userOrgMapSingle"))`